# Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this function to do a filter by jquery, and it is returning this error:

> Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined

```
 function VerificaCheck() { 
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, filtro;
    input = document.getElementById("busca2");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("tablepesquisa2");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    filtro = document.getElementById("filtroPesquisa2").value;
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[filtro];
        var tipoProduto = tr[i].getElementById("tipoProduto").value;
        if (td) {
            if (tipoProduto == $('#Produtos').prop("checked")) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the HTML of my table, and the checkbox. If the checkbox is checked it should look for in the table the fields of typeProduct that are true

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <select id="filtroPesquisa2" class="form-control">
                            <option value="0">Código</option>
                            <option value="1">Descrição</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <input type="text" id="busca2" placeholder="Pesquisa.." onkeyup="myFunction2();" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="table-overflow col-sm-12">
                        <table class="table table-responsive table-hover" id="tablepesquisa2">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Código</th>
                                    <th>Nome</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var item in Model.Produto)
                                {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@item.Codigo</td>
                                    <td>@item.nome</td>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <a href="#" onclick="fecha2();CarregaProduto('@item.Codigo');" title="Selecionar"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="tipoProduto" value="@item.TipoProduto">@item.TipoProduto</td>
                                </tr>
                                }

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

<input type="checkbox" asp-for="Produtos" onclick="checkProduto();" name="Produtos" id="Produtos"/>
```

Comment: Please give us a bit more context. From what you've posted, it's impossible to tell where this error is occurring. Could you also post a minimum, complete, and verifiable example including the relevant parts of the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById` is available on the document, not on `tr`.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

change the following line to

```
var tipoProduto = document.getElementById("tipoProduto").value;
```

However, this may not get what you want, based on my guesses that you have multiple elements by this id in your table. Post your html and what you are trying to do, may be there's another way to do this.

UPDATE:

As suspected, your `td` repeats in the loop, so you multiple `td` with same `id`. I'd suggest to remove id from it.
Since the value you are looking is the last `td`, what you can possibly do to get the value you are looking for is (one way that is):

```
td[td.length-1].innerHTML
```

So the loop would look more like:

```
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[filtro];

        if (td) {
            var tipoProduto = td[td.length-1].innerHtml;

            if (tipoProduto == $('#Produtos').prop("checked")) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this way it does not answer me, as it needs to check the data in the table, show the fields as marked in the checkbox.

Comment: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined, He is returning this error.

Comment: updated the answer, moving the td.length within the if block