# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, render, document

I'm trying to run one code that I have not created.
I'm getting the below error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined**

```
 Module.<anonymous>
C:/Users/src/index.js:6
  3 | import App from './App';
  4 | import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
  5 | 
 6 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
  7 | registerServiceWorker();
  8 | 
View compiled
```

I tried finding answers from the below links but was not able to relate them to my scenario.

- [Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840127/cannot-read-property-getelementbyid-of-undefined)
- [Puppeteer Cannot read property getElementById of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65800798/puppeteer-cannot-read-property-getelementbyid-of-undefined)
- [Cannot read property 'getElementById' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59792040/cannot-read-property-getelementbyid-of-null)

This is the below code from my index.js file

```
import React, { document } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Can anyone help me with this.
Let me know if want to know more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove `document` import from `react`. It should work.

Instead of

```
import React, { document } from 'react';
```

Use

```
import React from 'react';
```

You don't have to import it. It is available from the context.

Comment: @Amila -Again I'm getting the same error after I got navigated to the second page of the UI```TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined
App.componentDidUpdate. ``` Now not understanding where might be the issue.

Comment: @Jagruuti, can you create another question about that. I cannot see what has gone wrong now without seeing your code. please mark this as the answer to this specific question

Comment: Hey @AmilaSenadheera, I have removed ```document``` from every import now.